# how do i test javascript function with nested timeouts using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, onblur

I have the following function that will simply clear an input on blur. I'm using angular materials, and I'm creating a directive to be added when I want that to happen.

```
   function clearTextOnBlurLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {   
            $timeout(function() {
                var input = element.find('input'); 
                input.on('blur', function(e){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        input.val('');              
                        input.triggerHandler('input'); 
                    }, 100);                
                });
            },0);
        }
```

I want to test it, but I can't get it to work.

Here's my test:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$timeout_) {

                $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                $compile = _$compile_;
                $timeout = _$timeout_;        
                $scope.searchText = 'blah';

                element = angular.element('\
                    <div mx-clear-on-blur> <input ng-model="searchText1"> </div>\
                ');

               element = $compile(element)($scope);
               $scope.$apply();
               $timeout.flush();       
      }));
 it('clears text on blur', function() {
        var input = element.find('input').eq(0);

        expect(input.val()).toBe('blah');
        expect($scope.searchText).toBe('blah');

        input1.triggerHandler('blur');

        expect(input.val()).toBe('');
        expect($scope.searchText).toBe('');


    });
```

Ok, So I got it to work changing the setTimeout to $timeout.
Is there a less clunky way of doing that without the 2 timeouts?

Comment: You injecting $timeout, but inside your function you are using setTimeout which is not injected - so the code became async. You may try to mock input element with onValueChange hook. Or just use $timeout instead of setTimeout inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you're using `setTimeout` the second time around? Why not just use `$timeout` again...? Also `$timeout` is usually a bit of a code smell, so nested `$timeouts` feel a bit wrong tbh. :p

Anyway, I think for your test to pass you'd need a `$timeout.flush()` in your test after the blur.

Comment: I guess I didnt realize I was using settimeout.. dumb mistake. I changed it to $timeout and flushed after blur and it worked. I had that second flush but it didnt work because of setTimeout.
I'm using two timeouts for two reasons. The first one I need to that the page finished loading so I can add the event on an existing element. The second one is because I have added that directive to an autocomplete inside a chips. If I don't have a timeout, I can't select a chip, since it clears my selection when I select the chip.
If you have a more elegant solution, I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout inside your test too:

```
input1.triggerHandler('blur');
setTimeout(function() {
    expect(input.val()).toBe('');
    expect($scope.searchText).toBe('');
}, 100);
```

Jasmine should have also a waitsFor method:

```
input1.triggerHandler('blur');
waitsFor(function() { 
    return false; 
}, 100);
expect(input.val()).toBe('');
expect($scope.searchText).toBe('');
```